# Ubuntu wont boot after kernel update

Tags: ubuntu

Laptop: Thinkpad E14 Gen 2 AMD Ryzen 5 4500U
BIOS: latest 1.10
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5

My laptop boots properly when I use the default 5.4.65 kernel but when I try to update the kernel(tried 5.8.5, 5.8.10, 5.10.0,5.11.0) Ubuntu doesnt boot.
I get the following error:

[image: error message with quiet option]
[image: error message with verbose option]
[image: verbose after disabling snap]
[image: after snd blacklist]

Comment: Looks essentially the same as [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1297073/769591). Unfortunately that one has no answers either. But those latest errors seem to be about USB Type-C power management by ACPI, so not necessarily fatal. Check the kernel boot options in your bootloader: if they include `quiet`, remove that for one attempt. If there is no `quiet`, add `verbose` instead. That should result in a lot more messages describing all the steps of the boot procedure, and that should give better clues on what is actually stopping the boot process.

Comment: @telcoM I tried the verbose option , https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovHiq.jpg                                 Is there a way print this errors from a file while booting through my 5.4.65 working kernel?

Answer (score 4):

There are issues with AMD's virtualization subsystem under [newer Linux kernels (>= 5.5)](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-IOMMU-Linux-5.5) that are essentially implementation issues, which is to say that in your case, the ultimate solution for the issue should come from Lenovo in the form of a BIOS update which corrects the manner in which the Ryzen virtualizations are initialized.

Of course that does nothing to solve your issue in the here and now, so until then you'll need to find the correct kernel command line parameters that will disable or degrade the virtualization subsystem to a point where the boot process is able to continue past it with at most an error, as opposed to a panic. I don't have any Ryzen systems so I can't offer much certainty, but I believe you'll need to add one of the follows sets of parameters to your kernel command line:

- `iommu=soft`
- `iommu=soft pci=noaer`
- `amd_iommu_intr=legacy iommu=soft`
- `amd_iommu=off iommu=off`
- `amd_iommu=off iommu=off amdgpu.noretry=0 nox2apic`
- `acpi=off`

I'm afraid these sorts of issues are most often resolved with this sort of trial and error approach to discover what works for your particular hardware setup. Assuming you're booting using GRUB, you would test these extra parameters by pressing the <kbd>E</kbd> key on your keyboard after highlighting the kernel entry you wish to boot, find the line of the boot script that begins with `linux` (it's often indented from the left margin) and add these extra parameters to the end of the line. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot using the edited kernel command line and cross your fingers. Once you find a combination that allows the system to boot successfully, you would make those new parameters permanent by editing the file `/etc/default/grub` and placing them at the end of the line starting with **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`**, inside the closing quotation mark.

Depending on your need for hardware virtualization, another more straightforward approach would be to enter your UEFI BIOS settings by repeatedly tapping the <kbd>F1</kbd> key on your keyboard at two second intervals immediately after powering it on, until the BIOS Settings are displayed, and looking for the entry containing "AMD" and "Virtualization" in the name and switching its value to "Off" or "Disabled". You could then wait for the next UEFI BIOS release for your system (the current version is [1.10, released 2021-01-25](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e14-gen-2-type-20t6-20t7/downloads/ds544315-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-thinkpad-e15-gen-2)) and try re-enabling the virtualization setting after the update is successful.

Comment: I tried all the combinations of the boot parameters and disabled amd VT in bios, it still doesnt boot.

Comment: @concorde42 I'm sorry I wasn't able to help solve your issue. I honestly don't know what it could be, but I'll keep pondering on it and maybe some inspiration will strike. A couple more parameters you could try would be `pci=noacpi` or perhaps `acpi=strict`, but those are shots in the dark. Where are you getting your kernel packages? Are they Ubuntu Mainline builds? The full contents of the default kernel cmdline parameters would be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me                                                                                                                                           I used this script: https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh                               
to update the kernel...could this be the issue?                                                               Default kernel cmdline parameters: ro verbose splash $vt_handoff

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you've got troubles not with the new kernels but with userspace. Kernel messages between boots are **different** and not indicative of any freeze.

At same time the last systemd message looks suspicious and confusing: `mounting gnome-calculator`? Really? If I were you I'd try to remove all installed snaps under the kernel which still works and try again.

Comment: Should I disable snap ? Which files should I delete?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+snap+ubuntu

Comment: I removed snap it still doesn't boot. Got any other pointers for me?

Comment: Try booting *with* `verbose` (*remove* `quiet` as well) again and upload a picture.

Comment: Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5fi.jpg

Comment: I tried some of the older kernels....anything after kernel 5.4.99 doesnt seem to boot

Comment: Try the solution posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144090/snd-pci-acp3x-00000300-51-invalid-acp-audio-mode-1-lenovo-ideapad-330s-15

Comment: Blacklisting snd_pci_acp3x does fix the Invalid acp audio mode error while booting the 5.8.10 kernel. But now my older kernels dont work, it gets stuck on loading initial ramdisk or gets stuck like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMiE0.jpg . What should I do now? I cant boot into the older kernels.

Comment: I booted into recovery mode and removed the snd_pci_acp3x blacklist. Now I can boot into 5.4.65. Still cant boot into 5.8.10

Comment: So, do newer kernels work? To fix the issue for older kernels you can try booting in single mode, removing the blacklist configuration file and rebuild initrd.

Comment: If I were you I'd try something as fresh as possible (e.g. 5.11) and if your PC fails to boot, I'd file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ This has to be fixed for everyone.

Comment: Just tried with 5.10.17 and 5.11, does not work. A thing to note is that 5.11 doesn't show the error messages like the other kernels, but it is still stuck on Starting Plymouth! Guess I will file a bug report. Thanks for all the help.